# Properly registering DataContext for NancyFX

Tags: c#, nancy, tinyioc

I'm using NancyFX and Highway.Data + Entity Framework for an API project.  My module has a dependency on a repository, which has a dependency on an DataContext.  I need that DataContext to be registered and include the connectionstring from web.config, so I have this:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        //Gotta specify how to register the DataContext to use the connectionstring
        container.Register<IDataContext>(
            (c, p) =>
            new DataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString,
                            c.Resolve<IMappingConfiguration>()));

        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    }
}
```

This sets up the registration so it uses my web.config connectionstring, but also uses whatever IMappingConfiguration was already registered by auto-registration.

But it looks like it's registering it as a singleton instead of per web request.  This means that data gets cached between web requests, which is not what I want.

I've tried adding .AsMultiInstance() to the registration above, but then I get an error on startup:  "Cannot convert current registration of TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer+DelegateFactory to multi-instance"

Can anyone suggest how I can register this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container configurations should be performed in either `ConfigureApplicationContainer` or `ConfigureRequestContainer` depending on your life-time requirements.

Hope this helps

Comment: If I move my registration of the IDataContext into ConfigureRequestContainer or RequestStartup, the application fails to initialize because the modules are resolved in Application startup.

Comment: Yeah, I was misreading what was happening.  It turned out I needed to manually register more of the Highway.Data requirements in ConfigureRequestContainer to get it working correctly.